# Put elements in a line

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

I'm trying to put a H2 and a Div in a line and does not work

where I have the error?

```
<div style="display:inline"><h2>LISTA DE SEDES</h2> |<div class="Create">  @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<h2>` and the inner div should have `display:inline;`, not the outer div.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="display:inline"><h2 style="display:inline;">LISTA DE SEDES</h2> |<div class="Create" style="display:inline;">  @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")</div></div>
```

You should see:

```
LISTA DE SEDES | @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")
```

Displayed inline. You can also do it with floats:

```
<style type="text/css">
.float_left {
    float:left;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
</style>
<div class="float_left">
<h2 style="display:inline;">LISTA DE SEDES</h2>
</div> 
<div class="float_left"> | </div> 
<div class="float_left"><div class="Create">  @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")</div></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your nested `<div>` to display inline with your `<h2>` you need to apply `display: inline` to the nested div itself. Header elements are also displayed as a block by default, so you need to specify your `<h2>` to also display inline.

```
<div><h2 style="display: inline">LISTA DE SEDES</h2> |<div class="Create" style="display: inline">  @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")</div></div>​
```

See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/t5FEX/

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should used `display inline-block`

As like this

```
<div  style="display: inline-block;">
<h2 style="display: inline-block;">LISTA DE SEDES</h2> |
<div class="Create"  style="display: inline-block;">  @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")</div>
</div>
```

​​​​​​​​​Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/t5FEX/1/